# Under a periodic potential, is momentum a constant of motion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

During an online course of MIT, the professor mentioned that the momentum is not conserved while Hamiltonian is assumed to have a periodic potential. 
$$ [H,p] \neq 0 $$
Moreover, he added that the translation operator, which is translating functions in size of periodicity, will commute with Hamiltonian.

$$ [H,T_{L}] = 0 $$

I started to calculate the first commutation and end up with following,
$$[H,p] = i \hbar \frac {\partial V(x)} {\partial x} \psi(x) $$.

Then I tried to calculate second commutation but for arbitrary translation,
$$ [H,T_{x_{0}}] = [H,exp(-i \hat{p} x_{0}/\hbar)]   $$
$$T_{x_{0}} \psi(x)= exp(-i \hat{p} x_{0}/\hbar)\psi(x)= \psi(x+x_{0}) $$
Because $p$ is commutating with $p^{2}$ what is left is,
$$[H,T_{x_{0}}] = [V(x),T_{x_{0}}] $$
This commutation will be zero if we consider that $x_{0}=L$ because $V(x+L) = V(x)$.

In another approach we know that if operators $S$ and $T$ are commutating with $[S,T]$, then we will have,
$$[exp(tT),S] = t[T,S]exp(tT)$$
When I'm following this appraoch because I know that at least I can consider $V(x)$ in a way that both of  $p$ and $V(x)$ to commute with their commutation, we can use the last equaution and we will have.
$$[exp(-i \hat{p} x_{0}/\hbar) , V(x)]\psi(x) = x_{0} \frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x} \psi(x+ x_{0})  $$
If we set $x_{0}$ to be $L$, then, $[exp(-i \hat{p} L/\hbar) , V(x)]\psi(x)$ should be zero which means $L \frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x} \psi(x+ L)$ should be zero, but I can't see it. And if this holds it means that [H,P] is zero as well which is in conflict with assumption.

Comment: After thinking more, apparently, commutation of [[V(x), p], p] doesn't hold.